# Does Map and Reduce runs in separate JVM's?

Tags: hadoop

Hi I have a Map Reduce task say AverageScoreCalculator which has mapper and reducer.
the question is i static initialitze few fields in AverageScoreCalculator will that be avialable to both mapper and reducer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, each map and reduce task runs in a different JVM and there can be multiple JVMs running at any particular instance on a node.

Set the following properties

> mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks =  -1
>   mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum = 1
>   mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum = 1
>   mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps = 1

and there will be only a single mapper/reducer running on a given node with JVM reuse and the reducers won't start until all the mappers have completed processing.

Couple of things to note

1. The above approach works with MapReduce 1x release and is **not an efficient approach**.
2. JVM reuse is not supported in MapReduce 2x release.

Answer (score 1):

Static fields will create problem if they are updated dynamically in either map or reduce program. Standalone and pseudo-distributed modes are for beginners and should only be used if you are learning Hadoop. These mode wont help while processing huge volumes of data which is primary objective of map - reduce programming practice.

When jobs are distributed across the nodes , static information will be lost. Reconsider use of static variable.

If you can , paste the map and reduce program and the need for static fields , we can have a better solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should first know which configuration/mode your job is going to be run in.

For instance, if you run in  local(standalone) mode, there will be only one JVM running your job. 
If you run it in a pseudo-distributed mode, the job will be run using multiple JVMs on your machine.
If you run it in a distributed mode they will run on different machines and of course different JVMs (with JVM reuse)